Computation Cost of Automorphism Operation in RLWE-based homomorphic encryption
I would like to ask about the comparison of computational cost and time cost of the Automorphism operation Auto(), the homomorphic plaintext-ciphertext multiplication operation Mul(), and the homomorphic ciphertext rotation operation Rot() for the homomorphic encryption scheme based on RLWE.
(e.g Computational Cost: Auto()>Mul()>Rot()?)
